# separable equation2

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is this solution correct?

Equation:

$yy'-(1+y^2x^2)=0$

solve:

$yy'=1-y^2x^2$

$yy'-1=y^2x^2$

$\dfrac{yy'-1}{y^2}=x^2$

$\Rightarrow\dfrac{1}{2}\ln|y^2-1|=\dfrac{1}{3}\ln x^3+C$ .

Comment: Your third line is unclear.  Do you mean:
$$\frac{yy'-1}{y^2}=x^2$$
OR
$$yy' -\frac{1}{y^2}=x^2$$

Comment: In short, no, that equation is not separable, so you solution is incorrect.

Comment: It is not clear what is intended, but doesn't look right. You might make the substitution $z=y^2$. We end up with a linear equation.

Comment: Not sure how OP gets that last line, but both sides look wrong from here.

Comment: The answer reduces to $c^2x^2=|y^2-1|$ which is a union of the ellipse $y^2+c^2x^2=1$ and the hyperbola $y^2-c^2x^2=1$. Neither of these satisfies the original DE.

Comment: Thank you for time
Is my answer is wrong?
The question is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a few mistakes.  One was a subtraction error in your 2nd step, another was the integration step.

A way forward is to recognize that

$$y\,y' = \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dx} y^2$$

Then the equation is

$$\frac{d}{dx} y^2 - 2 x^2 y^2 = 2$$

Note that we now have an equation for $y^2$ rather than $y$.  The LHS may be simplified through the introduction of an integrating factor of

$$e^{-2 \int dx x^2} = e^{-2 x^3/3}$$

Then

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left [e^{-2 x^3/3} y^2 \right ] = 2 e^{-2 x^3/3}$$

The solution is then

$$y^2 = 2 e^{2 x^3/3} \int dx' e^{-2 x'^3/3} + C e^{2 x^3/3} $$

where $C$ is a constant of integration.  This is about as far as I can take this one.